# Formula for a curve

Tags: curves

Given a semicircle with center (0, 0) and radius 1. Draw two lines $d_1$ and $d_2$ parallel with the horizontal axis, and very close together. Then draw the reflection of those 2 lines as they hit the semicircle, and take their intersections $A$. If you move $d_1$ and $d_2$ together while keeping them the same distance apart, the path of $A$ will be a curve.

[image]

What is the formula of this curve?

Comment: I would start by figuring out the equation of the reflection line, when the initial beam is at altitude $d$. (Of course $|d|\leq 1$)

Comment: it's called a caustic; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caustic_(mathematics)